# Paging a GWT-EXT datagrid with GWT-RPC?

Tags: gwt, gwt-rpc, gwt-ext

I need to display data coming from a GWT-RPC service in a paginated datagrid.
The gwt-ext showcase does not provide an example combining gwt-rpc calls and datagrids.
That is too bad because the original javascript Ext grid components offer paging and remote sorting. How to take advantage of these features with GWT ?

Answer (score 1):

I too wanted to do this a few weeks ago, and searched long and hard and found nothing. In the end I wrote my own paged grid that supports RPC/Sorting/Editing/Etc.

It's intended to be generic, and is still a work in progress, but to use it you simply implement the TableSource and TableRenderer interfaces like so:

```
new PagedTable(new AssetTableSource(), new AssetTableRenderer(), 30);
```

I have posted the code here:

http://wiki.shiftyjelly.com/index.php/GWT#GWT_RPC_Paged_Table

Feel free to revert the buttons in the PagingControl.java back to normal GWT buttons.

Comment: Thanks but I would like to use Ext datagrids

Comment: Your link is dead